# Error inflating class com.androidplot.xy.XYPlot

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I am following this [tutorial](https://github.com/halfhp/androidplot/blob/master/docs/quickstart.md) to create graphs for an app I am developing, but the app keeps crashing and provides the following error message.

```
2021-06-11 13:35:11.259 13854-13854/com.example.dreuproject E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.dreuproject, PID: 13854
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.dreuproject/com.example.dreuproject.Tester}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7 in com.example.dreuproject:layout/tester: Binary XML file line #7 in com.example.dreuproject:layout/tester: Error inflating class com.androidplot.xy.XYPlot
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3654)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3806)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2267)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8167)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:496)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1100)
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7 in com.example.dreuproject:layout/tester: Binary XML file line #7 in com.example.dreuproject:layout/tester: Error inflating class com.androidplot.xy.XYPlot
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7 in com.example.dreuproject:layout/tester: Error inflating class com.androidplot.xy.XYPlot
 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:854)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:1006)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:961)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1123)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1084)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:682)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:534)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:481)
    at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:541)
    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:3369)
    at com.example.dreuproject.Tester.onCreate(Tester.kt:18)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7963)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7952)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1307)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3629)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3806)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2267)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8167)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:496)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1100)
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Error inflating XML: Setter requires param of unsupported type: class com.androidplot.ui.widget.TextLabelWidget
    at com.halfhp.fig.Fig.inflateParams(Fig.java:169)
    at com.halfhp.fig.Fig.configure(Fig.java:283)
    at com.halfhp.fig.Fig.configure(Fig.java:208)
2021-06-11 13:35:11.260 13854-13854/com.example.dreuproject E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.androidplot.Plot.loadAttrs(Plot.java:561)
        at com.androidplot.Plot.init(Plot.java:403)
        at com.androidplot.Plot.<init>(Plot.java:324)
        at com.androidplot.xy.XYPlot.<init>(XYPlot.java:143)
            ... 28 more
```

I am while I see that the error is pointing to a line in my Activity, the message provided seems to be more related to the layout file that the Activity is linked too.

I am very new to android so I am unsure on what the problem is.
Here's my Activity:

```
package com.example.dreuproject
import android.app.Activity
import android.graphics.DashPathEffect
import android.os.Bundle
import com.androidplot.util.PixelUtils
import com.androidplot.xy.*
import java.text.FieldPosition
import java.text.Format
import java.text.ParsePosition
import java.util.*

class Tester : Activity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.tester)

    val plot: XYPlot = findViewById(R.id.tester)
    var domainLabels: IntArray = intArrayOf(1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 13, 14)
    val series1Numbers: IntArray = intArrayOf(1, 4, 2, 8, 4, 16, 8, 32, 16, 64)
    val series2Numbers: IntArray = intArrayOf(5, 2, 10, 5, 20, 10, 40, 20, 80, 40)

    val series1: XYSeries = SimpleXYSeries(
        series1Numbers.toMutableList(),
        SimpleXYSeries.ArrayFormat.Y_VALS_ONLY,
        "Series1"
    )
    val series2: XYSeries = SimpleXYSeries(
        series2Numbers.toMutableList(),
        SimpleXYSeries.ArrayFormat.Y_VALS_ONLY,
        "Series2"
    )

    val series1Format: LineAndPointFormatter =
        LineAndPointFormatter(this, R.xml.line_point_formater_with_labels)
    var series2Format: LineAndPointFormatter =
        LineAndPointFormatter(this, R.xml.line_point_formater_with_labels_2)

    series2Format.getLinePaint().setPathEffect(
        DashPathEffect(
            floatArrayOf(
                PixelUtils.dpToPix(20F),
                PixelUtils.dpToPix(15F)
            ), 0F
        )
    )

    series1Format.setInterpolationParams(
        CatmullRomInterpolator.Params(
            10,
            CatmullRomInterpolator.Type.Centripetal
        )
    )
    series2Format.setInterpolationParams(
        CatmullRomInterpolator.Params(
            10,
            CatmullRomInterpolator.Type.Centripetal
        )
    )

    plot.addSeries(series1, series1Format)
    plot.addSeries(series2, series2Format)

    plot.graph.getLineLabelStyle(XYGraphWidget.Edge.BOTTOM).format = object : Format() {
        override fun format(
            obj: Any,
            toAppendTo: StringBuffer,
            pos: FieldPosition?
        ): StringBuffer? {
            val i = Math.round((obj as Number).toFloat())
            return toAppendTo.append(domainLabels[i])
        }

        override fun parseObject(source: String?, pos: ParsePosition?): Any? {
            return null
        }
    }

}
```

}

And here's my layout file

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ap="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.androidplot.xy.XYPlot
        android:id="@+id/tester"
        style="@style/APDefacto.Dark"
        androidPlot.title="My Plot"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        ap:domainTitle="domain"
        ap:lineLabelRotationBottom="-45"
        ap:lineLabels="left|bottom"
        ap:rangeTitle="range"
        ap:title="A Simple XY Plot" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line:

```
androidPlot.title="My Plot"
```

should be

```
ap.title="My Plot"
```

since you have defined the namespace as "ap", not "androidPlot".